# Slack API, get current location

Tags: node.js, slack-api

Is there any method to get current user location. Let say I created some "slash" command `/map`. When I am calling this command - POST message being send to my nodejs server, and server returns some json data.

```
{
    "channel": "#map", 
    "username": "test", 
    "unfurl_links": true,
    "icon_emoji": ":world_map:",
        "attachments": [
        {
            "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
            "pretext": "Beautiful Personalized Map Sharing",
            "image_url": "http://static.mapjam.com/yrjkbmb/auto/640x480.jpg",
            "thumb_url": "http://static.mapjam.com/yrjkbmb/auto/640x480.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Because I am authenticated I am able to get some Slack user info:

- username
- email etc..

How can I access Slack user lat, long if it is possible though

Answer (score 6):

Currently there is nothing available in the user info to get the geographical position of a user from the Slack API.

Please refer to the [Users Info Slack API documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info) and the U[ser Type documentation](https://api.slack.com/types/user).

Comment: This is the correct answer at the moment (March 2016).  Of course you can still send a link to the user and then get the location via the usual ways, but that's not really ideal as the user has to leave slack.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting to create a slash command the slack application would have to have permissions to your devices location. Looking at the permissions on my android app id does not request permissions to the devices location.

Just spit-balling, there could be a way to do it. This is completely hypothetical simplified method. You would have to have a helper application on the device that has permissions to the location of the device.  That app would listen for the /location /map request then post to the channel where the request came from.